# Does an interval and a triangle share the same homotopy type?

Tags: algebraic-topology

According to Hatcher's book, Chapter 0 page 12. He introduces one way to find homotopy equivalence instead of thinking deformation retract. He said we could collapse subspace to a point. So I have three questions.
1. I guess if we have a triangle, which is composed of three 0-cell and 3 one-cell, we shrink one edge, or collapse one edge to a point so that we get an interval, so they share the same homotopy type?
2. Does this word "collapse" have the same meaning with continuous deformation retract? 
3. So could I think deeply that every simplex could be contractible which means could shrink to a point?

Comment: Intervals are contractible; your triangles aren't.

Comment: But how to understand it according to Hatcher's introduction?

Comment: Contracting a side of your triangle does not result in an interval. The result is two intervals identified at their endpoints.

Comment: Why? A 0-cell on a triangle is the endpoint of two edges. If you identify this point to another, then two edges should move.

Comment: You can collapse an edge but you don't produce an interval. Because two other edges **are not** identified. You now have two points connected with two edges. A flatened circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess if we have a triangle, which is composed of three 0-cell and 3 one-cell, we shrink one edge, or collapse one edge to a point so that we get an interval, so they share the same homotopy type?

You don't get an interval. You get two points connected by two edges. That's because you didn't identify two other edges. Things don't "move" automagically. I know it is helpful sometimes to visualize it like that but the truth is that no such thing happens. You didn't identify them, so they are distinct.

In your construction the homotopy type doesn't change and in fact it is the homotopy type of a circle. Interval on the other hand has the homotopy type of a point. These two are not the same.

> Does this word "collapse" have the same meaning with continuous deformation retract?

If $A\subseteq X$ then **collapsing** $A$ means creating the space $X/A$ which is the quotient space with relation given by $x\sim y$ if and only if $x=y$ or $x,y\in A$. Collapsing a subspace may change homotopy type (e.g. take any noncontractible space and collapse everything). In some cases it does not, e.g. when $(X,A)$ is a CW pair and $A$ is a contractible subcomplex then the quotient map $X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence (see: Hatcher). This is exactly the case of your triangle.

> So could I think deeply that every simplex could be contractible which means could shrink to a point?

Yes, every simplex is contractible. Or more generally: every star subset of a normed vector space is contractible. Star subset is a subset $A\subseteq V$ such that there is a point $x\in A$ with
$$\forall_{y\in A}\ \ \forall_{t\in[0,1]}\ \ tx+(1-t)y\in A$$

So $A$ is contractible via

$$H:A\times[0,1]\to A$$
$$H(y, t)=xt+(1-t)y$$

Comment: Wow thank you again! So I guess intuitionally( forgive me, I like to seek for the right intuition first),  triangle has the same homotopy type with a circle, and if the interior of the triangle is full( that is what I understand "simplex", because all points on the path of two points which belong to the simplex are all in the simplex. So that means it should be like a disk, and I guess that is what you say about star subset), the disk of triangle shape should be contractible. Is that right?

Comment: I guess it is kind of like the difference between spheres and balls.

Comment: @Sooner Yes, exactly. Your tringle **is** sphere. And simplex **is** ball. Not "like", they are precisely the same up to homeomorphism. Not only homotopy.

Comment: Wow you proposed a problem that I always ignored. What is the difference between homotopy and homeomorphism? I know homotopy means that you need a continuous map between space A and B, and homeomorphism means that  we could find continuous bijective maps between A and B. So homeomorphism is the last stage of the homotopy , right? I mean for the $f_t$, the homeomorphism should be the $f_1$ because the $f_1$ is exactly the map we need to find for homeomorphism .

Comment: Also I remembered that simplex should be concerned about triangles. And the 3-simplex should be a tetrahedron instead of a ball although I know that tetrahedron and ball are the same homotopy type because we can find a way to deform the tetrahedron to a ball continuously.

Comment: Homeomorphism is an invertible function such that both the function and its inverse are continuous. From the topological point homeomorphic spaces are indistinguishable. They share all topological properties including homotopy type. For example $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic via tan function. So from topological point of view they are the same.

Comment: Homotopic spaces need not be homeomorphic. Example is given by an interval and a point. They cannot be homeomorphic because one is finite, the other is not. A more sophisticated example of homotopic but not homeomorphic spaces is $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: And yes, simplex is about triangles. But topologicaly triangles and balls are the same. It's just sometimes it is easier to work with one or another.

Comment: Thumb up for you! ( I don't know if the grammar is right but whatever, you know what I mean) So homoeomorphism is bijecitive, and it needs two continuous functions, one from A to B, another verses, but homotopy can only have one direction, for example the interval could shrink to a point but a point can not change to an interval. BTW, I guess R and (-$Pi$/2,$Pi$/2) should be homeomorphic :)

Comment: Hey could you help me solve the problem I proposed yesterday? I have been waiting for whole day but no one came here.